# how to load texture image to ply model in blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I can not load the texture image to ply model in blender, The image is empty, and it does not work
[image]

Comment: Instead of the Texture properties (red and black checkerboard icon) go to the material icon (red and black disc) and add a new material, set the color to image texture by clicking on the yellow dot on the left of field and select your texture. Does it work ?

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: You’re in solid viewport.